# What does "-weak_framework" mean in Xcode's Build Settings?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

[image]

Please refer to the above screenshot of [Cordova](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios) project, there is a -weak_framework key word under Other Linker Flags.

What does "-weak_framework" mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means the framework is "weakly linked", which means that the app can run on device/OS that doesn't have that particular framework available. It should only be used for frameworks that truly are not required and when code has properly been written to accommodate having those frameworks missing.

For example, one might want to mark SpriteKit as optional, so the app could still run on an OS that doesn't have it (for example, anything older than 7.0).