# RealityKit app and lower iOS deployment target

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, realitykit

I have an iOS app with deployment target iOS 10+, I need to add some features that depend only on RealityKit to appear with users whom their iOS version is 13+, the app compiles and runs successfully on real device but the problem is when archiving for upload to AppStore it generates a Swift file and says:

```
// "No such module RealityKit"
```

Sure the reason is related to iOS versions <13.0 but I can't edit that file (to add `canImport` to RealityKit) it's read-only.

My question is how to cross this problem and make it archive successfully with lower versions support?

Here is a demo that shows the problem when archiving [Demo](https://github.com/ShKhan9/RealTester).

[image]

Comment: Do you have any restriction on why you’re supporting a 5 year old version of iOS that not even Apple supports any more?

Comment: There are many users with iphone 5 and i need to support them as they are dropped at least on ios 11 which also won't solve the current issue

Comment: @Fogmeister can you try the demo may be there is something that can be done in build phases/settings or some where else , i guess it's a problem that opposites backward compatibility and there should be a solution to it ? i posted in Apple forums with no response

Comment: @rekopeek, Try my solution, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Firstly :

**Do not include Reality Composer's `.rcproject` files in your archive for distribution.** `.rcproject` bundles contain the code with iOS 13.0+ classes, structs and enums. Instead, supply your project with [USDZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018) files.

### Secondly :

To allow iOS 13+ users to use RealityKit features, but still allow non-AR users to run this app starting from iOS 10.0, use the following code (CONSIDER, IT'S A SIMULATOR VERSION):

```
import UIKit

#if canImport(RealityKit) && TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR

import RealityKit

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        arView.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(arView)
                
        let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.1))
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0,0,-2])
        anchor.addChild(entity)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
}    
#else

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

#endif
```

Deployment target is iOS 10.0:

[image]

### Thirdly :

When publishing to the AppStore (in case we have a deployment target lower than iOS 13.0), we must make the import of this framework `weakly linked` in the build settings (that's because RealityKit is deeply integrated in iOS and Xcode).

So, go to <kbd>Build Settings</kbd> –> <kbd>Linking</kbd> -> <kbd>Other linker Flags</kbd>.

Double-click it, press <kbd>+</kbd>, and paste the [following command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354840/what-does-weak-framework-mean-in-xcodes-build-settings):

```
-weak_framework RealityKit -weak_framework Combine
```

[image]

P.S. In Xcode 13.3, there's a project setting that also could help

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -weak_framework RealityFoundation
```

### Fourthly :

So, go to <kbd>Build Settings</kbd> –> <kbd>Framework Search Paths</kbd>.

Then type there the following command:

```
$(SRCROOT)
```

it must be **`recursive`**.

[image]

### Fifthly

The archives window:

[image]

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71110031/realitykit-feature-crashes-on-ios-13-4-1-but-works-in-15-2

Comment: AAndy Did you get the same case as i'm , the answer works for 15.2 but not for 13.4.1 it's very strange on running with real devices , btw i'm waiting for you

Comment: AAndy did you tried anything ?

Comment: AAndy  we did it in step 3 in your answer , aren't we ? if not where i could add this code ? BTW i already add `RealityFoundation` as weak

Comment: Note the usdz/.rcproject file is the rug on the video i have commented here my goal when the user changes device heading to some point to show/hide that rug this is the idea of the feature that i need

Comment: I think they previously add the rug to the space and manage the rotation/movement but i don't know what framework they use and how they use it ?

Comment: Could you provide a download link for the demo?
I tried the above method but it still doesn't work on the mobile device.

Comment: A demo using RealityKit on ios 10 version.
Implement code that can use `Secondly` code.

Comment: Could you help me solve this `lower iOS deployment target` problem on a demo? I could provide demo link. Thank you ……

Comment: Thank you for your help. https://github.com/7-Yue/RealityKitDemo This is demo.

Comment: Hi @ Andy Jazz, do you have some time this week to help me ?

Comment: Hi @CrystalBlack, I am back. Describe your problem with RealityKit, please.

Comment: Have you tried using `-weak_framework RealityKit` in `Build Settings –> Linking -> Other linker Flags` ?

Comment: I have tried it. But it not work.

Comment: Where does the crash occur: on real device or on the simulator?

Comment: On real device. If i set  deployment info to ios 13.0+, it will not crash. But in my develop project, i need adaptor lower version devices.

Comment: ...and what about simulator? (At the moment I have only device with iOS 15.5)

Comment: Try it in Simulator `#if canImport(RealityKit) && canImport(RealityFoundation) && TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried real device and simulator. Both versions are ios15. It's ok. Unfortunately, i just have ios15 simulator. ios 14 is downloading……  If simulator have no this question, but lower version real device still have this question. This seems to be an Apple bug.

Comment: Use `TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR`. ios14 real deivce will not use RealityKit and RealityFoundation. But  it support RealityKit feature.

Comment: I tried it on Simulator iOS 12.4 (Xcode 13.4) and on Simulator iOS 15.5 (Xcode 13.4). Both work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246049/discussion-between-crystal-black-and-andy-jazz).

Comment: At the moment I am at work (sorry). In 15 minutes my lesson starts.

Comment: Ok… Is there any other way I can chat with you.

Comment: @CrystalBlack, Yes, I agree with you... I tried to run the simulator in the morning - and I managed to run it 2 times without errors. But now, I'm trying to do the same - and my app keeps crashing. This is a real challenge for developers. It drives anyone crazy.

Comment: It's seem like a bug.  I have no find the answer to fix it. If you have find it,  message to me, please.

Comment: Ok, to be continued... )